# Ссылки e-mail

Tags: php

Как отобразить ссылку с анкором с помощью php mail при отправки на e-mail?
Сейчас весь код отправляется без какого-либо форматирования. Т.е. если я напишу

```
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">ХэшКод</a>
```

То оно так и отобразится

```
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">ХэшКод</a>
```

А не "[ХэшКод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужно отправлять не как текст, а как html! для чего нужно добавить хедеры

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

ну и добавлять их 4 параметром в   
`mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Источник [php mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)